# How could I create file in C when it is invoke from 4GL?

Tags: c, informix

I'm currently working on a C module of an Informix 4GL program. I was trying to put a debug log in the module like this:

```
int fgl_funcA(int i)
{
  FILE *pLog = NULL;
  pLog = fopen("debug.log", "a");
  fputs("fgl_funcA() called.", pLog);
  fclose(pLog);

  ...
  ...
}
```

But this function doesn't work at all. I mean it doesn't output `debug.log`. Even though I have manually create the file but somehow the content still not update yet. I was wonder whether I'm allow to create file in the C module when the code is call from 4GL?

Comment: Check if `pLog` is valid file pointer or not.

Comment: There is no way for me to check. I did try to put printf() to print something on the console to see whether pLog is a valid pointer. But it doesn't print anything on the console.

Comment: Are you sure that the function `fgl_funcA(int i)` is called ?

Comment: yes. I also purposely make some faulty code in it, and the compiler did complaining on the mistake.